# trouble understanding this while loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes an input of a list and an option which is either 0 or 1.  If it is 0, I want to return a list of element that are greater than the absolute value of 5.  If it is option 1, I want to return a list of elements are odd numbers.  I want to use a while loop also.  Where am i going wrong??

```
def splitList2(myList, option):
    nList = []
    element = 0 
    while element < len(myList):
        if option == 0:
            if abs(element) > 5:
                nList.append(element)
        elif option == 1:
            if element % 2:
                nList.append(element)
        element = element + 1
    return nList
```

Comment: didn't you just post this?

Comment: I already explained to you that you were using an index as if it were an element, and calling it `element` was confusing you, and that you could fix it by renaming it and then (a) replacing `element` with `myList[index]` everywhere it appeared or (b) adding `element = myList[index]` to the top of the loop. Nobody is going to have anything different to tell you here.

Comment: @abarnert and I didn't understand that part.  I'm just a beginner and even with the right code its hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes:  OP posted a clear specification and code sample, and the question is on-topic, generic and clearly put.  If I'd expect any rants here, it would be te missing broken output and redirections to codereview at most.  But downvotes?

Comment: @AloisMahdal: If you read the OP's previous question, and his comments on it, it looks an awful lot like he's trying to get people to write his homework assignment for him, rather than to actually teach him enough to write his own code. He claims he understood my answer to his first problem, but if that were true, there's no way he would have made the exact same mistake again on the second problem and been clueless how to even begin solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` is an index, not an element from `myList`.  I would rename your current `element` variable to something like `index` and then add `element = myList[index]` at the top of your while loop:

```
def splitList2(myList, option):
    nList = []
    index = 0 
    while index < len(myList):
        element = myList[index]
        if option == 0:
            if abs(element) > 5:
                nList.append(element)
        elif option == 1:
            if element % 2:
                nList.append(element)
        index = index + 1
    return nList
```

Of course it would be simpler to just use a `for element in myList` loop here instead of your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `element` as a name for the element index, which is confusing.  And indeed, later you examine/append the index instead of corresponding element from myList!

Alternative version:

```
def splitList2(myList, option):
    nList = []
    n = 0 
    while n < len(myList):
    element = myList[n]
        if option == 0:
            if abs(element) > 5:
                nList.append(element)
        elif option == 1:
            if element % 2:
                nList.append(element)
        element = element + 1
    return nList
```

also `while` is not the best choice for such a task.  I assume you are trying to do this using `while` for educational reasons.  However, a much more Pythonic way is:

```
def splitList2(myList, option):

    options = {
        0: lambda n: abs(n) > 5,
        1: lambda n: n % 2
    }

    return filter(options[option], nList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create two lists for both cases you want and iterate the given list without any index variable?

```
def splitList2(myList):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for element in myList:
        if abs(element) > 5:
            list1.append(element)
        if element & 1: # check the 0 bit
            list2.append(element)
return list1, list2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer only the "where am I going wrong?" question.

1. You have two different problems. The belong in two different functions, which you will debug independently of each other.
2. You have chosen using a "while loop" as a part of the solution. It might be a part of the solution, but it might be a bad approach. Perhaps it is good for none, one, or both of your problems.
3. You are new to python and maybe programming in general. Nothing wrong with that. Good luck. You should learn to reduce problems to their simplest form before attempting any solution. Usually for any problem you have, you can find a number of smaller problems that are easy to solve. Solve them one by one, then integrate the solutions to the small problems into the a solution to the original problem.
4. In each of the 2 problems, you are likely to find that in python the 'for element in iterable:' is preferred. Example, 'for word in words:', 'for item in alist', etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
nList.append(myList[element])
```

you really shouldn't name the index element, that's where your confusion's from

Comment: still is giving me the wrong answer after doing this step. @prgao